# How do I compare two arrays ignoring the last 4 characters the variables in the 2nd array?

Tags: php, arrays, replace, compare

I am trying to compare two arrays but ignore the last four characters in the 2nd array, here are the two arrays:

```
$a1 =array("Maths Foundation","Maths Higher","English Foundation","English Higher","English Lit Foundation","English Lit Higher");

$a2 = array("Maths Foundation 2015","Maths Higher 2014","English Foundation 2015","English Lit Higher 2014");
```

I want $a2 to look at $a1 and replace the matching subjects and replace the none matching subject with " ". So the result would look like this:

```
$a3 = array("Maths Foundation 2015","Maths Higher 2014","English Foundation 2015"," ","English Lit Higher 2014");
```

So $a3 would replace the missing "English Lit Foundation" with " "

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I think I am close, here is my code so far:

```
$a1=array("Maths Foundation","Maths Higher","English Foundation","English Higher","English Lit Foundation","English Lit Higher");

$subjects = array("Maths Foundation 2015","Maths Higher 2014","English Foundation 2015","English Lit Higher 2014");
$subject = array();
$subjectyr = array();

foreach ($subjects as $v){
$yr = substr($v, -4);
$subb = substr($v, 0, -5);
$subject[] = ''.$subb.'';
$subjectyr[] = ''.$subb.' '.$yr.'';


$a3 = $a1;

$results = array_keys(array_diff($a1, $subjectyr));
foreach ($results as $result)
$a3[$result] = '';
}
$a4 = array_replace($a3,$subjectyr);
$string1 = implode(", ",$a4);
echo $string1;
```

/////////////////////EDIT//////////////////////////////////

I've decided to try another tactic and its getting closer, still not there yet though:

```
$a1=array("Maths Foundation","Maths Higher","English Foundation","English Higher","English Lit Foundation","English Lit Higher");

$a2 = array("Maths Foundation 2015","Maths Higher 2014","English Foundation 2015","English Lit Higher 2014");

foreach ($a1 as $a11){foreach ($a2 as $a22){
$a3 = substr($a22, 0, -5);
if ($a3 == $a11){
$thing[] = $a22;
}
else {
$thing[] = "";
}}}
print_r ($thing);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a1 =array("Maths Foundation","Maths Higher","English Foundation","English Higher","English Lit Foundation","English Lit Higher");
$a2 = array("Maths Foundation 2015","Maths Higher 2014","English Foundation 2015","English Lit Higher 2014");

$temp = array();
$out = array();

foreach($a2 as $element)
    $temp[substr($element, 0, -5)]=$element;

foreach($a1 as $element)
    $out[]=isset($temp[$element])? $temp[$element] : ' ';

var_dump($out);
```

Outputs:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "Maths Foundation 2015"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "Maths Higher 2014"
  [2]=>
  string(23) "English Foundation 2015"
  [3]=>
  string(1) " "
  [4]=>
  string(1) " "
  [5]=>
  string(23) "English Lit Higher 2014"
}
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/pDmoZd

Comment: Thanks for looking but the result needs the years attached like in $a3 in the example and to replace "English Lit Foundation" with "".

Comment: @user1721230 Oops, i mis-read your question. Please see my revised answer. Unlike the currently accepted answer it replaces `"English Higher"` with `" "` as well, as this is not in the second array either.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $a1 =array("Maths Foundation","Maths Higher","English Foundation","English Higher","English Lit Foundation","English Lit Higher");
    $a2 = array("Maths Foundation 2015","Maths Higher 2014","English Foundation 2015","English Lit Higher 2014");
    $a3 = array();

    foreach($a2 as $k1 => $v1) {

        foreach($a1 as $k2 => $v2) {

            if (substr($a2[$k1], 0, -5) == $a1[$k2]) {
                $a3[] = $a2[$k1];
                break;
            } elseif (count($a1) == ($k2+2))
                $a3[] = "  ";

        }

    }

    var_dump($a3);

?>
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(21) "Maths Foundation 2015"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "Maths Higher 2014"
    [2]=>
    string(23) "English Foundation 2015"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "  "
    [4]=>
    string(23) "English Lit Higher 2014"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I was chasing my tale a little and over-complicating it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$found = 0;
foreach ($a1 as $key => $value) {
    $found = 0;
    foreach ($subjects as $k => $v) {
        if ($value == $substr($v, 0, -5)) {
            array_push($subject, $v);
            $found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($found == 0) {
        array_push($subject, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I cant figure out where to put that.

Comment: Insert the code below 
$subjectyr = array();
the array $subject will contain your result.